# How do you create a Matplotlib widget in Kivy kv file?

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy, kivy-language

I want to use a .kv file to make a Matplotlib widget, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Without a .kv file, the basic code looks like this:

```
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 23, 2, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        box = BoxLayout()
        box.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
        return box

MyApp().run()
```

How is this done with a .kv file?

Answer (score 3):

So here's what I figured out. In the .KV language file you specify a layout and give it an id:

```
BoxLayout:
    id: destination
```

Then in your python code you use the following:

```
self.ids.destination.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
```

So effectively you're using the id you setup in the kivy language file as a reference for your matplotlib graph.

Comment: I do not get how to work your code. From the example above, you add the`self.ids.destination.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))` in a MyApp `__init(self)__` method?

Comment: You can put it anywhere, in a function or method that you're calling. If you want to plot the graph as soon as the window spawns, then you'd put it into the build method for your App class.

I'm actually using it in a custom method that gets called whenever I drop a file on the window. So I drop a file on the window, and it plots the data to a graph for me.

Comment: You are a life saver. Having bumped into so many endless road I finally realised the referencing id can be made directly. I used self.root.ids.destination.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf())) instead

Comment: @astroflyer I had a mare of a time getting this working originally, so I'm glad my answer helped!!

Answer (score 0):

You (and I) need to extend FigureCanvasKivyAgg as in John Anderson's answer to [Python to KV Lang - FigureCanvasKivyAgg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54252521/python-to-kv-lang-figurecanvaskivyagg):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
from kivy.app import App
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 23, 2, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')

class MyFigure(FigureCanvasKivyAgg):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(plt.gcf(), **kwargs)

class MyApp(App):
    pass

MyApp().run()
```

The kv file for the above question:

```
BoxLayout:
    MyFigure:
```

This fix also enabled me to set the position of the figure:

```
FloatLayout:
    MyFigure:
        pos: (400, 20)
        size: (300, 200)
        size_hint: (None, None)
```