# Python to KV Lang - FigureCanvasKivyAgg

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Can I write the FigureCanvasKivyAgg under my code, using KV Lang?
I need to insert button and customize the boxlayout in the function "on_enter" and I think it would be easier to have the graph written in KV Lang.

The problem that I am having now, is that I tryied to add a button in the "grafico screen", although the button appears from one moment and after that, the graph takes place in the box layout. 
I was wondering that if I can write everything in KV Lang it would be easier to have a box layout, button and so on.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("module://kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivy")
from kivy.garden.matplotlib import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import numpy as np


f = 10 #frequency
x = np.linspace(0,1,200)
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*x)


class Gerenciador(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Menu(Screen):
    pass

class Sensores(Screen):
    pass

class Grafico(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        box = BoxLayout()
        box.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
        self.add_widget(box)

class sensor(App):
        def build(self):
            return Gerenciador()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sensor().run()


    KV LANG

#:import np numpy
#:import FigureCanvasKivyAgg kivy.garden.matplotlib


<Gerenciador>:
    Menu:
        name: 'menu'
    Sensores:   #analogo a nossa tela 01
        name: 'sensores'
    Grafico:
        name: 'grafico'

<Menu>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 200
        spacing: 50
        Image:
            source: 'logo.png'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 200
            allow_stretch: True
        Button:
            text: 'Lista de Sensores'
            on_release: app.root.current = 'sensores'
        Button:
            text: 'Sair'
            on_release: app.stop()

<Sensores>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 50
        spacing: 10
        Button:
            text: 'Sensor 01'
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = 'grafico'
        Button:
            text: 'Sensor 02'
        Button:
            text: 'Sensor 03'
        Button:
            text: 'Sensor 04'


<Grafico>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.09
            pos_hint: {"x": .1 , "y": .2}
            text: "Atualizar"
```

I need to have the same results that I have now, but using KV Lang.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but perhaps [Kivy_Matplotlib](https://github.com/jeysonmc/kivy_matplotlib) would work here.

Answer (score 3):

Kivy widgets used in `kv` must have a no positional arguments `__init__()` method. The `FigureCanvasKivyAgg` extends `Widget`, but has a required `__init__()` argument, which is the figure, so you cannot use that directly in `kv` (a poor design choice, in my opinion).

But you can make a hack that might work for you. The following depends on having a figure available before the `sensor` app is started. You can extend the `FigureCanvasKivyAgg` as:

```
class MyFigure(FigureCanvasKivyAgg):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyFigure, self).__init__(plt.gcf(), **kwargs)
```

Note that `MyFigure` has no required positional arguments. But it calls the `FigureCanvasKivyAgg.__init__()` with the required figure argument. This is why the figure must already be available.

You can then use `MyFigure` in your `kv` file as:

```
<Grafico>:
    BoxLayout:
        MyFigure:
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.09
            pos_hint: {"x": .1 , "y": .2}
            text: "Atualizar"
```

Of course, the `on_enter()` method of your `Grafico` class must be removed.