# Points of line of canvas in kivy are not updated

Tags: python, canvas, kivy, line

I want to make a real time graph but I can't update the points of line of canvas in my code, I can update the background colors and values of labels and buttons, but with canvas I can't make it

I have tried in a similar way as I update buttons and labels but it simply doesn't update, I put the basic code and how I update labels and button, it runs and you can see the line, with clock it should update as the another stuff after 5 seconds, thank you for your help.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty,\
    ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector

Prin2ON = 0
points = (0,0,0,0,0,0)

class Site21(Button):
    pass
class Site22(Button):
    pass
class Site23(Button):
    pass
class Hora(Button):
    pass
class Horas12(Button):
    pass
class Horas24(Button):
    pass
class Semana(Button):
    pass
class Mes(Button):
    pass

class WelcomeScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WelcomeScreen, self).__init__()

        number = 1
        def count_it2(number):
            global Prin2ON

            #Originally I update these values from a db
            number1,number2,number3,number4 = 1,2,3,4
            self.ids.tempP2.text = str(number1)
            if number1 <= 25:

               #Here is how I update background colors and it works
               self.ids.tempP2.background_color = 0, 1, 0, 1
            if number1 > 26 and number1 <= 28:
               self.ids.tempP2.background_color = 1, 1, 0, 1
            if number1 > 28:
               self.ids.tempP2.background_color = 1, 0, 0, 1
            self.ids.humeP2.text = str(number2)
            if number2 <= 20:
               self.ids.humeP2.background_color = 0, 1, 0, 1
            if number2 > 21 and number2 <= 40:
               self.ids.humeP2.background_color = 1, 1, 0, 1
            if number2 > 41:
               self.ids.humeP2.background_color = 1, 0, 0, 1
            self.ids.humoP2.text = str(number3)
            if number3 <= 40:
               self.ids.humoP2.background_color = 0, 1, 0, 1
            if number3 > 41 and number3 <= 45:
               self.ids.humoP2.background_color = 1, 1, 0, 1
            if number3 > 46:
               self.ids.humoP2.background_color = 1, 0, 0, 1
            if Prin2ON == number4:
                self.ids.Princip2.color = 1, 0, 0, 1
                self.ids.tempP2.text = str("No data")
                self.ids.tempP2.background_color = 0, 0, 0, 0
                self.ids.humeP2.text = str("No data")
                self.ids.humeP2.background_color = 0, 0, 0, 0
                self.ids.humoP2.text = str("No data")
                self.ids.humoP2.background_color = 0, 0, 0, 0
            else:
                self.ids.Princip2.color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            Prin2ON = number4

            Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: count_it2(number), 5)

        def count_it8(gra):
            global points

            #Here is where I don't know how update the points
            self.ids.grapic.line = (self.x, self.y+100, self.x+200, self.y+150, self.x+300, self.y+500)
            Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: count_it8(gra), 5)

        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: count_it2(0), 0)
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: count_it8(0), 0)

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Monitoring system'
        return WelcomeScreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

And here is the kv code:

```py
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
<WelcomeScreen>:
    display: display
    rows: 1
    GridLayout:
        cols: 4

        Label:
            id: grr
            text: "Estación"
        Label:
            id: display
            text: "Temperatura [C]"
        Label:
            id: display
            text: "Humedad [%]"
        Label:
            id: display
            text: "Humo [ppm]"


        Label:
            id:Princip2
            text: "Prin2"
        Site21:
            id:tempP2
            text: ""
            on_release: root.site_one()
        Site22:
            id:humeP2
            text: ""
            on_release: root.site_one()
        Site23:
            id:humoP2
            text: ""
            on_release: root.site_one()



    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        GridLayout:
            id: grapic
            cols: 1
            size: 25, 200
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: .1, 1, .1, .9
                Line:
                    width: 1.2
                    points: (self.x, self.y+50, self.x+200, self.y+100, self.x+300, self.y+200)
                Line:
                    width: 1.
                    rectangle: (self.x+30, self.y+100, self.width-50, self.height-200)

        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, 0.15
            cols: 5
            Hora:
                text: "Hora"
                on_release: root.site_one()
            Horas12:
                text: "12 Horas"
                on_release: root.site_one()
            Horas24:
                text: "24 Horas"
                on_release: root.site_one()
            Semana:
                text: "Semana"
                on_release: root.site_one()
            Mes:
                id: display
                text: "Mes"
                on_release: root.site_one()
        #Label:
            #id: display
            #font_size: dp(50)
            #text: "0"
```

Comment: It works better using matplotlib https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50012762/how-do-you-create-a-matplotlib-widget-in-kivy-kv-file

Answer (score 0):

You can update your line by using an `ObjectProperty` that contains the points, and then just update that `ObjectProperty`. To start, add the `ObjectProperty` to your `WelcomeScreen` class as:

```
class WelcomeScreen(GridLayout):
    line_points = ObjectProperty((0,0,0,0))
```

Then reference that property in your `kv`:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    GridLayout:
        id: grapic
        cols: 1
        size: 25, 200
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: .1, 1, .1, .9
            Line:
                width: 1.2
                points: root.line_points  # references ObjectProperty
            Line:
                width: 1.
                rectangle: (self.x+30, self.y+100, self.width-50, self.height-200)
```

Now you can just update the `line_points` object to effect the change you want:

```
    def count_it8(gra):
        global points

        #Here is where I don't know how update the points
        self.line_points = (self.x, self.y+100, self.x+200, self.y+150, self.x+300, self.y+500)
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: count_it8(gra), 5)
```

The key is that the reference to the `root.line_points` property in `kv` sets up a binding for you, so that any change in the `line_points` will automatically update the line.

Comment: Thank you John now it update but it plots in all the window starting from a corner and not in the corresponding area and do not respect the "self.x and self.y" to adjust when I maximize the window, I will continue to try to fix that.

Comment: Yes, may answer only addresses how to update the `Line` points, not what values you use as points. If you want the line to respond to changing window size, have a look at [bind](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.event.html#kivy.event.EventDispatcher.bind).